# Php login via email in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Hi guys i have loging via email , and i want to add login via email.
When i add (login=:login OR) in sql query, i got bug you can login by any password.

Here some code :

```
public function login($login,$upass)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE login=:login OR email=:login LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':login' => $login));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            if ($userRow['userStatus'] == "Y") {
                if ($userRow['haslo'] = $upass) {
                    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['idKlient'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    header("Location: index.php?error");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php?error");
            exit;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

i'm trying to add password_hash(), but when i login in my website is going down.
i tried to add password hash but my website is going down when i login in.

```
public function login($login, $upass)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE login=:user_login OR email=:user_login");
            $stmt->execute(array(":user_login" => $login));
            $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            if ($userRow['userStatus'] == "Y") {
                if ( password_verify($upass, $userRow['haslo'])) {
                    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['idKlient'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    header("Location: index.php?error");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php?error");
            exit;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change here add param for email also

```
    $stmt->execute(array(':login' => $login,':email' => $login));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($userRow['haslo'] = $upass) {
```

You're giving $userRow['haslo'] the password, you need to check it with ===
And please, use hashing not plain-text, check [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE login = :login: OR email = :email: LIMIT 1")
$stmt->execute(array('login' => $login, 'email' => $upass));
```

And my suggestion is that you check variables before exec, something like:

```
if(isset($login) && isset($upass)) {
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to use the same named parameter twice in a single SQL statement, for example

```
<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE  some_value > :value OR some_value < :value'; 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute( array( ':value' => 3 ) ); 
?>
```

...this will return no rows and no error -- you must use each parameter once and only once. Apparently this is expected behavior (according to this bug report: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886) because of portability issues.